# what is the pure javascript version of sending data from html forms?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I currently use jQuery to send data from my html forms then I use php to store it in my database. Here is the code I use:

HTML FORM :

```html
<form id="formpost" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return false">
<input type="text" id="text2" name="status" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Question....?"/><br/>
<textarea id="text1" name="status2" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Description....." rows="6"></textarea><br/>
<button id="postbutton" class="btn btn-danger">POST</button>
</form>
```

jQuery File:

```js
$ (document).ready(function() {

//mama code
$("button#postbutton").click(function() {

 var data = $("#formpost").serialize();
 
$.ajax({

type: "POST",

url: "data.php",

data: data,

success: function(data) {
 location.reload();
}

});



});



});


$ (document).ready(function() {
 $.ajax({

type: "POST",

url: "data2.php",


success: function(data) {

$("#statustext").append(data);


}

});
});
```

I have two ajax request, data.php sends the html form inputs into my database and data2.php retrieves that data on success and appends an empty html div.

My problem altogether was that I had a working application but when I installed a text-area editor my content from my html forms was not storing into my database. So if I use clean JavaScript the application would run. Any code in clean javascript would be appreciated to send data from my html form using ajax calls. Thanks

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com.au/?gws_rd=ssl#q=jquery+ajax+pure+javascript&spell=1) is your friend: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-make-ajax-requests-with-raw-javascript--net-4855

Comment: you could leave out js altogether. simply submit the form to a php page

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to use pure javascript. What "text-area editor" are you using? I believe it is possible that you are using some javascript plugin (maybe TinyMCE?) so when it loads the textarea is repleaced with some other HTML that is not submitted on the POST request. 
If this is the case you could manually add the data from the text-editor. For example in the ajax call:

```
...

data: $("#formpost").serialize();
data.content = $("#text-editor).val(); 
...
```

/// $("#text-editor") - this is the texarea used for the editor

You should read the documentation of the plugin you are using to see how to retrieve the content of the text-editor.

Comment: I used tinymce and ckeditor but they both won't work

Comment: With TinyMCE you get the content in the editor by writing this: tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();
Here is link to the relevant documentation: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:method.tinymce.Editor.getContent

Comment: Include it right before you send the ajax request in the $("button#postbutton").click() event